# LinkedIn Network Updates returns null

Tags: linkedin-api

The following query returns null for me in the brwoser. However, just removing the &count=250, I start seeing some results. Though, it is still not the entire set of results, still.

Note that this happens only with few access tokens. Other users within my app are fine.

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates?oauth2_access_token=XXXXXXXX&format=json&count=250

Thanks,
Kushal.